# Implode Array by Comma

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I have this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(1) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
array(1) {
  ["ID"]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
```

And I want to have an output of this: `3, 6, 9`

How can I concatenate or implode those array values to put in a variable so that I will use that variable with a value of like this:  `3, 6, 9` in this: `$this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', $imploded);`

Answer (score 4):

Use the function [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the ID from each element into a single-dimensional array, then `implode` as usual:

```
echo implode(',', array_column($array, 'ID'));
```

If you are running PHP earlier than 5.5 then `array_column` is not available out of the box, so you have to provide equivalent code such as

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($r) { return $r['ID']; }, $array));
```

That said, your proposed usage of the final result (sticking a comma-separated integer list representing item ids into a database field) is unusual and possibly wrong. For many-to-many relationships (each user can have many roles, and each role can be assigned to many users) the standard implementation is to use a join table, keeping your database schema normalized.

Comment: Sorry but I have a question. Where does $array came from?

Comment: @user987654321: It's the array that you have.